# Reducing a path to simplest value?

Tags: python

Is there an os.path function to reduce a path to its simplest form? For example, is there a way to reduce `/a/b/c/../../` to `/a/`?

I've tried `os.path.abspath(url)` but this prepends my home directory as well. For example, if I want `www.google.com/a/index.html` it returns `/Users/myname/Documents/www.google.com/a/index.html`

Obviously one possible solution is to remove `/Users/myname/Documents/` from all paths that I create, but I feel like there must be a better way...

Comment: What do you mean by simplest form?  Local/relative path?  If so, you probably don't want to be using `os.dir.abspath`.

Comment: os.path is meant for filenames. Is there a reason your function is trying to operate on filenames and website URLs? Normally those are two very separate things. abspath will only prepend your home directory if there is no leading forward slash: os.path.abspath('/home/dest') --> '/home/dest'

Comment: `os.path.normpath('/a/b/c/../../')` --> `/a` or check `os.path.relpath` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath)

Comment: @BorrajaX perfect! os.path.normpath was exactly what I wanted! Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You could do something like this:

```
print(os.path.abspath("/a/b/c/../../") + os.path.sep)
print(os.path.normpath("/a/b/c/../../") + os.path.sep)
# both print /a/
```

If you work with real paths and python 3.4, you can also use pathlib:

```
import pathlib
print(pathlib.Path("/tmp/tmux-1000/../").resolve() )
```

Comment: what does os.path.sep do?

Comment: @Apollo It add `/` to path. Otherwise the result would be `/a` and not `/a/`.